# A polynomial function representing Logical OR

Tags: polynomials, boolean-algebra

Is there a way to represent logical OR function of two or more variables as a polynomial/value function.

So that the $f(x,y)>0$ if $\text{OR}(x,y)>0$.

Additional Edit: Considering $\geqslant 0$ means TRUE, and $<0$ means FALSE. For both the variables and the function. i.e in case $x>0$ and $y<0$, $\text{OR}(x,y)>0$ but $f(x,y)$ might depend on the relative magnitudes of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So which is it:  is True any value that is $>=0$, or is it any value strictly $>0$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need to use this function for?

Comment: It will be used in a controller synthesis. Suppose the x and y are the constraints that a system needs to follow, so how much their value is greater than zero suggests how robustly that constraint is being followed.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function 
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\frac{x}{|x|}+\frac{y}{|y|},
\end{equation}

- Is greater than or equal to $0$ when $x<0$ is and $y\geq0$.
- It is also negative when both of $x<0$ and $y<0$.
- It is positive when $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$.

This satisfies the requirements of logic OR where $f(x,y)\geq 0$ corresponds to true, and $f(x,y)<0$ corresponds to false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $OR(x,y)=1-(1-x)(1-y)$. Assuming $0$ is false and $1$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $f(x,y) = x + xy + y \mod 2$ works.

Comment: Sorry for the edit later, but I needed x and y to be scalars instead of boolean.